# Namespace `store` does not exist in windows.services

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to access the `StoreRequestHelper` class from with a WPF application via desktop-bridge. I've followed the instuctions here: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#JP6H2BjHQoLxE5GS.97 and I am able to successfully call other UWP methods such as `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri)`. I've also downloaded the sample project [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/StoreSample) which uses the assembly I'm looking for. As far as i can tell, I have all the correct references but I'm still getting this error. Would anyone be able to assist?

Here is my references vs the sample project references.
[image: References]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong about the instuctions I followed. I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-enhance which seems to somehow cause an issue. I removed all references and re-added them from the other article (https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#JP6H2BjHQoLxE5GS.97) and that seemed to sort everything.

Answer (score 1):

Neither link in the accepted answer solved the issue for me. Adding a reference to `Windows.Services.Store.StoraContract.winmd` did it.

I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way to do it, but I found this based on the .dll name provided in Microsoft's documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store, and it seems to work fine. The exact location of the file would depend on the version you're targeting; I used the one at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract\4.0.0.0`. I otherwise followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-enhance, including the setting of "Copy Local" for the reference to false.